# Safari on MacBookPro opens mobile YouTube

Tags: macos, safari, youtube

After WWDC2020 I can't open common YouTube in Safari on my MacBookPro 2020. I'm being redirected to m.youtube.com each time which looks just like on iPad or iPhone. The main problem is that I can't watch any video "because macOS doesn't recognize internet addresses starting with rtsp:" (I see this when I start any video). What to do about it?

UPD: I have macOS Catalina 10.15.5

UPD#2: I have a default user agent and changing it to any other doesn't help.

Comment: Did you change the User Agent to "Safari - iOS 13.1.3 - iPhone" (or similar) under Development>User Agent?

Comment: @jaume I have a default user agent

Comment: Maybe try removing the "m." part from your address bar and check if it works

Comment: @Pulakesh I've tried it too, doesn't help :C (it still redirects to m.youtube.com and I can't figure out how to change it)

Comment: Have you tried deleting caches/cookies/local storage for youtube.com, m.youtube.com, google.con, accounts.google.com etc., and then restarting Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the next solution: clicked on my avatar, then settings. There was the sacred button "full-version"